# AngularFire2 and Child Events

Tags: angular, angularfire2

What is the correct way to implement `Child Events` in `AngularFire2`?

Like `value`, `child_added`, `child_changed`...
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events

I tried to find in the documentation, without success.

---

If AngularFire2 does not implement this, is there any way to do it in Angular2?

Comment: AngularFire2 does not expose the events - it aggregates them into an array (for the `list` observable) or an object (for the `object` observable). If you want to use them, use the Firebase Web API - the use of which in conjunction with AngularFire2 is [encouraged](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/854).

Comment: @cartant Thanks! But using the list I cannot know witch entry is new/modified, right?

Comment: Which entry in an AngularFire2 `list`? No, it's not something that is supported. An oversight, if you ask me. You'd have to look at the snapshot's `key` and then scan the array, looking at each item's `$key` property.